# How to run the CSS Autoprefixer WebJar using SBT?

Tags: playframework-2.0, less, sbt, webjars, autoprefixer

I am working on a Play framework project where I will be using both [LESS](http://lesscss.org) and [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). My goal is to get these to run in sequence so that when I compile my code, it will run LESS and then run autoprefixer. I am trying to set this up through SBT, but I am finding little documentation to help me.

There are two potential Autoprefixer projects to use - one is a WebJar and the other is [sbt-autoprefixer](https://github.com/matthewrennie/sbt-autoprefixer). Including the WebJar doesn't break the build, but it doesn't do any prefixing either. The other library has a version incompatibility with my code, and I would prefer to use a WebJar over including a git: URI in my code as a dependency anyway.

What do I need to do in order to get the WebJar version of Autoprefixer to work? There is no documentation on the WebJar that I can locate.

Answer (score 0):

You need an sbt-web plugin to run the autoprefixer so you will need to get the sbt-autoprefixer plugin working.

Comment: Well, I need a 2.11 build for that to work, and it seems that sbt-js-engine is also still on 2.10. Do you know if there are plans to get these sbt plugins up to date? I will contact the repository administrator.

Comment: None of the sbt plugins for Play 2.3 are on 2.11 yet.  Your project can still use 2.11 but your build must use 2.10.

Comment: I am encountering a conflict between Akka actors built for 2.10 and 2.11 and am not sure how to resolve such an issue.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more details about that conflict in another questions.